# Angular primeNg pEditableColumn dropdown onChange event

Tags: java, angular, primeng, primeng-datatable, primeng-dropdowns

I have a p-table with p-editable column which is a dropdown as follows:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns" let-editing="editing">
    <tr style="font-size:10px;" [pEditableRow]="rowData" >
        <ng-container *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngSwitch]="col.field">
            <td *ngSwitchCase="'dob'" [colSpan] = "1">
                {{rowData[col.field] | date: 'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm'}}
            </td>
            <td *ngSwitchCase="'updated'" [colSpan] = "1">
                {{rowData[col.field] | date: 'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm'}}
            </td>
            <td *ngSwitchCase="'assignedTo'" [colSpan] = "1" pEditableColumn>
                <p-cellEditor>
                <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                    <p-dropdown [options]="assigneList"  [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" (onChange)="changeAssigne($event)" ></p-dropdown> 
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                    {{rowData[col.field]}}
                </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td *ngSwitchDefault [colSpan] = "1">
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </ng-container>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

As per primeNg documentation assigneList has a label, value in addition I have an id field that is unique for each row.

My dropdown works perfectly fine foreach row and corresponding element gets selected perfectly. However, I have a requirement where onChange of dropDown I have to update the DB.

My onChange function which is changeAssigne(event), currently displays only value. I want the onChange to give me the entire object.

Component.ts code

```
...///
assigneList : BoardAssigneDTO[] =[];

this.assigneList = this.data.assigneList;


///..
```

and model is as follows:

```
export class BoardAssigneDTO {
    id : Number = 0;
    label : string = '';
    value : string = '';
}
```

So in this case my onChange should have object in the form BoardAssigneDTO which has id, label, value. How can this be done.

Initially, I was trying to pass just object as id, Name, Country but dropdown wouldnt work. So followed as per documentation [primeNG table edit with dropdown](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/edit)  and created label and value pair which is concat of name and country.

But my unique key is id and I want to pass this id to the backend. How is this possible? Any suggestions highly appreciated.

Comment: However normal dropdown which is not inside p-table works fine. The onChange event for those dropdowns gives the entire object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work as it is for normal dropdowns if it is inside a **p-table**.

By default p-dropdown value is mapped to value property in option list object.

I have used the below approach to fix achieved this long time back.

Add the event and pass the value and list:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="assigneList"  [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" (onChange)="changeAssigne(assigneList,rowData[col.field])" ></p-dropdown>
```

Find the object and assign to model in `changeAssigne` method

```
changeAssigne(list,value){
   // find out the object from list
   let selectedItem = list.filter((item)=>{
     return item.value === value;
   });
   console.log(selectedItem);// selected option object
}
```